# "Made in planet earth" or "made on planet earth"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm confused about this. We usually say 'Made in China', but what about planet Earth?

Comment: Good question. The reason is that the metaphors we use for countries and for the earth are not the same. In English, countries are a bounded area. We use the preposition *in* when we thing about enclosed areas, *fields, squares, gardens, enclosures, cities* etc. The Earth, in contrast, being a ball, is not enclosed. We say *on earth* because *on* is the preposition we use with surfaces, and when we say *on earth* we are kind of saying 'on (the surface) of the earth.'

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, I think that both usages must be seen as metaphorical, with '**on** Earth' more transparent than '**in** China'. 'On fire', 'on time', 'on the sly', 'on the increase' are opaque.